# Discord trying to remove mentions including usernames and nickname

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
all_content = re.sub(r'!([A-Za-z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:\'\",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]{2,32})|[\w]{2,32} rolled [\w]+ (\(\d+)\/(\d+\))', '', message.content).strip()
```

I am using `re.sub(r'<@!?(\d+)>|<@&?(\d+)>', '', all_content)` to remove mentions with username and nickname but the output shows as `<@` instead of nothing.

Comment: Can you attach sample input and expected output ?

Comment: Input: `https://i.imgur.com/3a3VXaR.jpg @name`
Output: `https://i.imgur.com/3a3VXaR.jpg <@`

Comment: Why dont you just split on sapce `" "` to seperate the hyperlink and `@name`?

Comment: I want the output to be `https://i.imgur.com/3a3VXaR.jpg` and not including any mentions.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It can be achieved using `your_string.split(" ")[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a message object, you can use [Message.clean_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Message.clean_content) to get the "clean" content of the message